# Get user ID for database insert

Tags: users, 8

I have a form inserting into a database in Drupal 8. I would like to insert the user id. I have the following code:

```
$userCurrent = \Drupal::currentUser();
$uname = (int)User::load($userCurrent->id());
```

Without the (int) Drupal throws an error saying it cannot be converted into a string. With the (int) Drupal always returns 1. What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: As stated I would like the user ID not the user name. Sorry if it doesn't make sense, I am very new to Drupal and there is not a lot of documentation for 8 yet.

Comment: `User::load()` returns a `User` object; if you cast it to `int`, you don't get what you want.

Comment: The fact you store the value in `$uname` makes me think you are trying to obtain the username, and your code is wrong. May you say what exactly you are trying to achieve. Saying what `User::load()` returns is probably just the tip of the iceberg.

Comment: Also, if you are really looking for the username, you can get directly \Drupal::currentUser()->getAccoutName()/getDisplayName(). As others said, there are many things about your question that don't make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to get the username, as the variable name suggests?

```
$uname = User::load($userCurrent->id())->name->value;
```

Your question does not make sense, why load the user with the id to get the id, you already have?

Comment: Sorry, no I want the user id

Comment: The user id is `$uid = $userCurrent->id()`